# How to pass the useState method to a component and this component returns the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

My Home.js file I have:

```
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({});

<Search setLocation={{ setLocation }} />
```

In my Search.js file I have:

```
const Search = (setLocation) => (
  <Container>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder="Onde você esta?"
      onPress={(data, details) => {
        setLocation(data, details.geometry.location);
      }}

some code...
```

I got this error:
setLocation is not a function. setLocation is an instance of object

How can I change the location State?

Comment: did you get the prop `setLocation` by destructuring?

Answer (score 1):

first thing you're sending method to Search component in object. so you are getting this

```
error: setLocation is not a function. setLocation is an instance of object
```

you are trying to execute nested object {{setLocation}} onPress GooglePlace.

send method as a prop like this

```
<Search setLocation={setLocation} />
```

than you get setLocation as object in Search component like this

```
{setLocation}
```

change your Search component this way

```
const Search = ({setLocation}) => (
  <Container>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder="Onde você esta?"
      onPress={(data, details) => {
        setLocation(data, details.geometry.location);
      }}
     />
</Container>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this form.

```
<Search setLocation={setLocation} />
const Search = ({setLocation}) => (...
```

Answer (score 0):

From **React js** official docs, you should lift state like this:

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
const handleLocation = (args) => {
  setLocation(args)
}
<Search onLocationChange={ handleLocation } />
```

Search.js

```
const Search = ({onLocationChange}) => (
  <Container>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder="Onde você esta?"
      onPress={(data, details) => {
        onLocationChange(data, details.geometry.location);
      }}

some code...
```